# Setting up geddy.js project on heroku

Tags: heroku, geddy

I am new in `nodejs` development and I am using [geddyjs](http://geddyjs.org/documentation) for development. Problem is I couldn't find any solution for setup geddyjs project on  [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com) following command is used to execute project

```
cd projectfolder
geddy
```

But couldn't find how I can setup geddy to execute project? I couldn't find solution on heroku dev thats why I am posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation to deploy Nodejs Application on Geddydocumentation:

http://geddyjs.org/guide#deployment_heroku

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this page from the docs will help:

http://geddyjs.org/documentation#deploymentHeroku